# Java script new Function access external methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code as follows(the code is in vue. but its a generic javascript query)

```
 <v-checkbox :value="getValue(layout.responseNode)" @change="setValue(layout.responseNode, $event);expression(layout.onChange)" :label="expression(layout.label)" :disabled="expression(layout.enableIf)" ></v-checkbox>
```

In this i'm trying to run two statements on change setValue and an expression(to clean up node).

So for expression I have made

```
 expression(expr) {
        var fn = new Function('dataObject', expr)
        var result = fn(this.dataObject)
        return result

    }
```

In this I'm able to pass data via dataObject. But I have some methods outside like 'dropNode','minallowed' etc.. in another file. How to pass that to "new Function()" of javascript?

Now getting error
[image: Error]

Comment: This is likely XY problem. It's unclear what you try to achieve. new Function shouldn't be used under normal circumstances. Consider reasking the question and explaining your case

Comment: Here expression(Layout.Onchange) will be dynamic script, which server will give. To run this dynamically  I got 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

in my case Layout.Onchange will be dynamic expression dropNode('Response.HeartRate')

Sorry about my english. I will update the question if its clear

Comment: If you're able to modify that script to suit your case, you will likely need to do that. It's not going to work the way you try it to do.